How do Nextflow and AWS Batch are working together on an architectural level?
I am new to both AWS Batch and nf and I have some doubts. I have a question about the interaction between nf and aws. Think that you want to run the nf horse process locally and you want to run the single processes on aws. Nf will pull images from docker and AWS Batch will create copies of the custom AMI I have to run those processes. Correct? If so, how do nf and AWS Batch communicate. How does batch know which docker image should be run on the ec2 instances allocated for the single processes.
I understood that head processes also read and write files from/on the working directory. So there should also be some kind of communication between the processes on aws and the local horse process. It's this infrastructural part that I am not quite well understanding. Thank you everyone for the attention. Any suggestion is welcomed!
